# xampp lite ver 1.7.7 not able to send emails

Tags: php, email, xampp, sendmail.exe

I am tryign to send email using xampplite version 1.7.7.

I changed my PHP.ini file wit the following:

```
[mail function]
; For Win32 only.
; http://php.net/smtp
;SMTP = localhost
; http://php.net/smtp-port
;smtp_port = 25

; For Win32 only.
; http://php.net/sendmail-from
;sendmail_from = postmaster@localhost

; For Unix only.  You may supply arguments as well (default: "sendmail -t -i").
; http://php.net/sendmail-path
sendmail_path = "\"\xampp portable\sendmail\sendmail.exe\" -t"
```

I also downloaded the latest version of sendmail application and made the following chages to it, ofcourse replaced it with my email informations.

```
smtp_server=smtp.gmail.com
smtp_port=465
smtp_ssl=auto
auth_username=myemail@gmail.com
auth_password=mypassword
force_sender=myemail@gmail.com
hostname=smtp.gmail.com
```

I am stil unable to send email making above changes, if someone can help then please let me know thanks.

Comment: who named `sendmail.exe` on `unix`?

Comment: you were able to send it in that fashion with (some other) xammp before? Via gmail account??

Comment: i am using the xampp on windows and not on unix and therefore it has a .exe file for sendmail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If there is an ; before the line, it means that it's commented out

Comment: Yes I know that but lines that are commented out should be commented out according to tutorial on one of the source.

Comment: Can you give me the source please?

Comment: Hi,I followed this tutorial.

http://mattwad.wordpress.com/2011/11/13/send-emails-from-xampp-lite-on-windows/

Comment: I have managed to get this working. The problem was that I had the pop setting enabled too and that was causing the problem follow the tutorial link given above if anyone has this problem.